# vim :gsearch (greplace plugin) escaping characters

Tags: vim, grep, macvim

I am using the greplace plugin for vim and am not sure how to escape brackets in a search.

I want to search for cookies[:parent] and have tried:

```
:Gsearch cookies[:parent] # returns nothing
:Gsearch cookies\[:parent\] # returns nothing
```

How should I be doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:Gsearch cookies\\\[:parent]` works for me.

Remember that :Gsearch requires a file mask in addition to the pattern, so in reality, you'd want to type something like `:Gsearch \\\[:parent] *.php` or whatever, to specify which files you want to have searched.

Comment: Thanks, I was using a file mask just didn't type it in here. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Gsearch cookies\\\[:parent\\\]
```

or

```
Gsearch 'cookies\[:parent\]'
```

. If I understood correctly, shell invoked by `:grep!` invoked by `:Gsearch` gets string `grep -n cookies\[:parent\] /dev/null` (assuming grepprg option has default value) and thus your escapes are interpreted by shell that thinks they are for escaping `[` in order to prevent glob expansion. But after globbing done by shell grep takes argument as a pattern, so you need to escape it for grep also and it is why I have three backslashes here: two are to make grep get a backslash and third to prevent glob expansion.

Answer (score 0):

```
:Gsearch cookies\[:parent]
```

[ is the start of a character class, so needs to be escaped. The ] isn't particularly special so doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: It does not need to, but `\]` is not a metacharacter and neither is `]`.